# Javascript Logical Operator:?

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword

I was examining the src of underscore.js and discovered this:

```
_.isRegExp = function(obj) {
    return !!(obj && obj.test && obj.exec && (obj.ignoreCase || obj.ignoreCase === false));
};
```

Why was "!!" used? Should it be read as NOT-NOT or is there some esoteric JS nuance going on here?

Comment: It's called a shorthand, not an esoteric JS nuance. In the same way that the `+`  operator is used to convert to a number (e.g.: `+"0"`) and that `+""` is used to convert to a string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the !! operator in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 12):

It is just an obtuse way to cast the result to a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's NOT-NOT. It is commonly used idiom to convert a value to a boolean of equivalent truthiness.

JavaScript understands `0.0`, `''`, `null`, `undefined` and `false` as falsy, and any other value (including, obviously, `true`) as truthy. This idiom converts all the former ones into boolean `false`, and all the latter ones into boolean `true`.

In this particular case,

```
a && b
```

will return `b` if both `a` and `b` are truthy;

```
!!(a && b)
```

will return `true` if both `a` and `b` are truthy.

Comment: You forgot `NaN` (as being falsey).

Answer (score 1):

The && operator returns either false or the last value in the expression:

```
("a" && "b") == "b"
```

The || operator returns the first value that evaluates to true

```
("a" || "b") == "a"
```

The ! operator returns a boolean

```
!"a" == false
```

So if you want to convert a variable to a boolean you can use !!

```
var myVar = "a"
!!myVar == true

myVar = undefined
!!myVar == false
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is just two ! operators next to each other. But a double-negation is pointless unless you are using !! like an operator to convert to Boolean type.

It will convert anything to true or false...